# Помогите найти ошибку в небольшом коде js

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! Верстаю сайт по видео, учусь. Код ниже должен открывать и закрывать подменю, но уменя этого не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```js
document.addEventListener("click", documentActions);

function documentActions(e) {
    const targetElement = e.target;
    if (targetElement.closest('[data-parent]')) {
        const subMenuId = targetElement.dataset.parent ? targetElement.dataset.parent : null;
        const subMenu = document.querySelector('[data-submenu="${subMenuId}"]');
        const catalogMenu = document.querySelector('.catalog-header');

        if (subMenu) {
            catalogMenu.classList.toggle('_sub-menu-show');
            targetElement.classList.toggle('_sub-menu-active');
            subMenu.classList.toggle('_sub-menu-open');
        } else {
            console.log("No exsist");
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header__catalog catalog-header">
        <div class="catalog-header__container">
            <nav class="catalog-header__menu menu-catalog">
                <ul class="menu-catalog__list">
                    <li class="menu-catalog__item">
                        <button data-parent="1" class="menu-catalog__link">Каталог ножей</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-catalog__item">
                        <button data-parent="2" class="menu-catalog__link">Клинковое оружие</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-catalog__item">
                        <button class="menu-catalog__link">Сувенирные изделия</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-catalog__item">
                        <button class="menu-catalog__link">Фонари ARMYTEK</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-catalog__item">
                        <button class="menu-catalog__link">Сопуствующие товары</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="menu-catalog__sub-menu sub-menu-catalog">
                    <div class="sub-menu-catalog__container">

                        <div data-submenu="1" class="sub-menu-catalog__block">

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column">
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__category">Категория ножей</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu-catalog__list">
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Разделочные ножи</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Туристические ножи</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи охотничьи</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Булатные ножи</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из дамаска</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Тактического назначения</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Метательные ножи</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Мачете и кукри</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи кухонные</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__all">Смотреть все</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column">
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__category">Производство ножей</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu-catalog__list">
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи АИР</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи ЗИК</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи ЗЗОСС</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи РОСоружие</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи Оружейник</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Булат Сергея Баранова</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Булат Андрея Умерова</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи Златко</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи Стиль-М</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Оружейная компания</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__all">Смотреть все</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column">
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__category">Ножи по маркам стали</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu-catalog__list">
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали 40х102С2М</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали 95х18</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали 100х13м</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали 110х18м-ШД</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали ЭИ-107 ТЦ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали 50х14МФ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали AUS-8</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали К340</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали M390</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножи из стали ЭП-766</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__all">Смотреть все</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column">
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__category">Заточка и полировка ножей</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu-catalog__list">
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Паста ГОИ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Алмазная паста</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Бруски и камни для заточки</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Заточные системы</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__all">Смотреть все</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column">
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__category">Ножевая мастерская</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu-catalog__list">
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Ножевые клинки</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Заготовки для ножей</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Литье для ножей</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Материалы для рукоятей</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="sub-menu-catalog__item">
                                        <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__link">Уход за рукоятиями ножей</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="" class="sub-menu-catalog__all">Смотреть все</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div data-submenu="2" class="sub-menu-catalog__block">

                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column"></div>
                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column"></div>
                            <div class="sub-menu-catalog__column"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте отладку  плюс возможно вам нужен слушатель на DOMContentLoaded .... обе ссылки в дубликатах выше

Comment: Спасибо, попробую